# dompdf stream() method throw DivisionByZeroError

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am trying to generate PDF and it throws me an error from vendor/

There is exactly used like https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf said, and it was worked before.

```
  DivisionByZeroError 

  Division by zero

  at vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/Table.php:169
    165▕                     $auto_max = $max_width - $absolute_used;
    166▕ 
    167▕                     foreach ($auto as $i) {
    168▕                         $max = $columns[$i]["max-width"];
  ➜ 169▕                         $w = $max + $increment * ($max / $auto_max);
    170▕                         $cellmap->set_column_width($i, $w);
    171▕                     }
    172▕                 }
    173▕                 return;

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  app/Pdf/Docgenerator.php:22
      Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::stream()

  18  app/Pdf/InvoiceMacro.php:26
      App\Pdf\Docgenerator::htmlToPdf()
```

Any ideas why it doing it?

I am using Ubuntu OS, Laravel 8, php8.0

Below is Docgenerator.php content

```
<?php

namespace App\Pdf;


use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Mpdf;

class Docgenerator
{
    public static function htmlToPdf($html, $password = null)
    {
        if (config('app.env') == 'testing') {
            return file_get_contents(resource_path() . '/test.pdf');
        }
        $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf->loadHtml($html);
        if ($password) {
            $pdf->setEncryption($password);
        }
        return $pdf->stream('dompdf.pdf');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$auto_max` is 0, so `$max_width` and `$absolute_used` must be the same number. Double-check your values.

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1057 - Double-check your document structure

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032812/laravel-with-php8-1-seeders-does-not-works-properly?